# Simple mathematic solution doesnt work

Tags: php, math

I want to compare the results to each other so if $ship < $given = destroyed= show echo. It only works for sec90, the others at one time forget the post enemy > weapon part so it only shows ship > trader46 even if the enemy gets destroyed before.

Here the part for an example:

```
if($ship > $_POST[trader46])
{
$taken = $_POST[trader46] * 2;

if($ship > $taken)
{
$taken3 = $_POST[trader46] * 3;
if($ship > $taken3)
{
$taken4 = $_POST[trader46] * 4;
if($ship > $taken4)
{
$taken5 = $_POST[trader46] * 5;
if($ship > $taken5)
{
$taken6 = $_POST[trader46] * 6;
if($ship > $taken6)
{
$taken7 = $_POST[trader46] * 7;
if($ship > $taken7)
{
$taken8 = $_POST[trader46] * 8;
if($ship > $taken8)
{
$taken9 = $_POST[trader46] * 9;
if($ship > $taken9)
{
$taken10 = $_POST[trader46] * 10;
if($ship > $taken10)
{
$taken11 = $_POST[trader46] * 11;
if($ship > $taken11)
{
$taken12 = $_POST[trader46] * 12;
if($ship > $taken12)
{
$taken13 = $_POST[trader46] * 13;
if($ship > $taken13)
{
$taken14 = $_POST[trader46] * 14;
if($ship > $taken14)
{
$taken15 = $_POST[trader46] * 15;
if($ship > $taken15)
{


if($_POST[enemy] > $weapon2)
{
$given = $weapon2 * 2;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given)
{
$given3 = $weapon2 * 3;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given3)
{
$given4 = $weapon2 * 4;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given4)
{
$given5 = $weapon2 * 5;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given5)
{
$given6 = $weapon2 * 6;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given6)
{
$given7 = $weapon2 * 7;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given7)
{
$given8 = $weapon2 * 8;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given8)
{
$given9 = $weapon2 * 9;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given9)
{
$given10 = $weapon2 * 10;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given10)
{
$given11 = $weapon2 * 11;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given11)
{
$given12 = $weapon2 * 12;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given12)
{
$given13 = $weapon2 * 13;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given13)
{
$given14 = $weapon2 * 14;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given14)
{
$given15 = $weapon2 * 15;
if($_POST[enemy] > $given15)
{
echo "Enemy still stands at minute fifteen";
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fifteenth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fourteenth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the thirteenth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the twelvth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the eleventh minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the tenth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the ninth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the eight minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the seventh minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the sixt minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fifth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fourth minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "U destroyed the enemy in the third minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "u destroyed the enemy in the second minute";
}
}
else
{
echo "enemy destroyed in the first minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the fifteenth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the fourteenth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the thirteenth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the twelvth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the eleventh minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the tenth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the ninth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the eight minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the seventh minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the sixt minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the fifth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the fourth minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the third minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the second minute";
}

}
else
{
echo "u got destroyed in the first minute";
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code on an external site that expires in 6 days.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: the code was too long to post it here without code block and for that i would need to put 4 spaces before each line ...

Comment: Then just post the relevant code. See this from other people's point of view, if you cannot take your time to provide a clear question, then people cannot help. I for one will not be going to an .xyz site given their reputation for spam, sorry

Comment: Stack overflow is here, not only to help you, but also to help other people. If there are questions with parts missing then the answers make no sense, and the whole idea behind SO falls to bits.

Comment: Read up on [mcve] for posting shorter code.

Comment: it cant be any shorter, i didnt cut parts , the code works on sec90 so u need the whole thing to compare whats wrong... its not about posting shorter code , i have a serious problem the math isnt working correct. i have edited it with the code not working

Comment: I mean no offence here, just trying to help you :) your code is really bad in terms of structure, that makes it very hard to read, understand, and maintain. I've had a look but the nesting of your IF and ELSEs makes it impossible to see which value relates to what echo. I'm not sure if you can store these in an array with matched values or not, but you need to do something to make it cleaner :)

Comment: Actually, I'd guess your issue is because of the nesting, it "seems like" each IF can only happen if the previous one is true, but again it's hard to read so that might be a wrong assumption

Comment: yes they should do that theres no other way, in the battle i need to figure out when ship lasts trader46 (damage of the enemy) wether it would last weapon * 2 and even check if enemy life is greater then weapon damage . when i reconstruct it and take only a few values it works. but not with 15 times....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said that there is no other way to do it. I hope you don't mind that I took the liberty to do so, anyway. If you structure the code somehow like below, you will make future-you much happier:

I assume that you have the following variables: `$shipLife` is the life amount of the player, `$shipDamage` is the damage dealt by the planer, `$enemyLife` is the life amount of the enemy and `$enemyDamage` is the damage dealt by the enemy.

```
//advance time $t with a for loop at most until minute 15
for($t = 1; $t <= 15; ++$t) 
{
    //perform enemy attack
    $shipLife -= $enemyDamage;

    //check if the ship survived the attack
    if($shipLife <= 0)
    {
        echo "You got destroyed in minute " . $t;
        break;
    }

    //perform ship attack
    $enemyLife -= $shipDamage;

    //check if the enemy survived the attack
    if($enemyLife <= 0)
    {
        echo "You destroyed the enemy in minute " . $t;
        break;
    }
}

//Check if both players are still alive
if($shipLife > 0 && $enemyLife > 0)
    echo "Both ship and enemy are still alive after " . ($t - 1) . " minutes";
```

Comment: This is certainly a lot easier on the eye! Point from me. Whether it does what it should, I can't tell.... but it is certainly a valiant attempt.

Comment: this works totally :) thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I reformated you code online with http://phpbeautifier.com/beautify.php

```
<?php

if ($ship > $_POST[trader46]) {
  $taken = $_POST[trader46] * 2;
  if ($ship > $taken) {
    $taken3 = $_POST[trader46] * 3;
    if ($ship > $taken3) {
      $taken4 = $_POST[trader46] * 4;
      if ($ship > $taken4) {
        $taken5 = $_POST[trader46] * 5;
        if ($ship > $taken5) {
          $taken6 = $_POST[trader46] * 6;
          if ($ship > $taken6) {
            $taken7 = $_POST[trader46] * 7;
            if ($ship > $taken7) {
              $taken8 = $_POST[trader46] * 8;
              if ($ship > $taken8) {
                $taken9 = $_POST[trader46] * 9;
                if ($ship > $taken9) {
                  $taken10 = $_POST[trader46] * 10;
                  if ($ship > $taken10) {
                    $taken11 = $_POST[trader46] * 11;
                    if ($ship > $taken11) {
                      $taken12 = $_POST[trader46] * 12;
                      if ($ship > $taken12) {
                        $taken13 = $_POST[trader46] * 13;
                        if ($ship > $taken13) {
                          $taken14 = $_POST[trader46] * 14;
                          if ($ship > $taken14) {
                            $taken15 = $_POST[trader46] * 15;
                            if ($ship > $taken15) {
                              if ($_POST[enemy] > $weapon2) {
                                $given = $weapon2 * 2;
                                if ($_POST[enemy] > $given) {
                                  $given3 = $weapon2 * 3;
                                  if ($_POST[enemy] > $given3) {
                                    $given4 = $weapon2 * 4;
                                    if ($_POST[enemy] > $given4) {
                                      $given5 = $weapon2 * 5;
                                      if ($_POST[enemy] > $given5) {
                                        $given6 = $weapon2 * 6;
                                        if ($_POST[enemy] > $given6) {
                                          $given7 = $weapon2 * 7;
                                          if ($_POST[enemy] > $given7) {
                                            $given8 = $weapon2 * 8;
                                            if ($_POST[enemy] > $given8) {
                                              $given9 = $weapon2 * 9;
                                              if ($_POST[enemy] > $given9) {
                                                $given10 = $weapon2 * 10;
                                                if ($_POST[enemy] > $given10) {
                                                  $given11 = $weapon2 * 11;
                                                  if ($_POST[enemy] > $given11) {
                                                    $given12 = $weapon2 * 12;
                                                    if ($_POST[enemy] > $given12) {
                                                      $given13 = $weapon2 * 13;
                                                      if ($_POST[enemy] > $given13) {
                                                        $given14 = $weapon2 * 14;
                                                        if ($_POST[enemy] > $given14) {
                                                          $given15 = $weapon2 * 15;
                                                          if ($_POST[enemy] > $given15) {
                                                            echo "Enemy still stands at minute fifteen";
                                                          }
                                                          else {
                                                            echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fifteenth minute";
                                                          }
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                          echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fourteenth minute";
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                      else {
                                                        echo "U destroyed the enemy in the thirteenth minute";
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                    else {
                                                      echo "U destroyed the enemy in the twelvth minute";
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                  else {
                                                    echo "U destroyed the enemy in the eleventh minute";
                                                  }
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                  echo "U destroyed the enemy in the tenth minute";
                                                }
                                              }
                                              else {
                                                echo "U destroyed the enemy in the ninth minute";
                                              }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                              echo "U destroyed the enemy in the eight minute";
                                            }
                                          }
                                          else {
                                            echo "U destroyed the enemy in the seventh minute";
                                          }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                          echo "U destroyed the enemy in the sixt minute";
                                        }
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fifth minute";
                                      }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                      echo "U destroyed the enemy in the fourth minute";
                                    }
                                  }
                                  else {
                                    echo "U destroyed the enemy in the third minute";
                                  }
                                }
                                else {
                                  echo "u destroyed the enemy in the second minute";
                                }
                              }
                              else {
                                echo "enemy destroyed in the first minute";
                              }
                            }
                            else {
                              echo "u got destroyed in the fifteenth minute";
                            }
                          }
                          else {
                            echo "u got destroyed in the fourteenth minute";
                          }
                        }
                        else {
                          echo "u got destroyed in the thirteenth minute";
                        }
                      }
                      else {
                        echo "u got destroyed in the twelvth minute";
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      echo "u got destroyed in the eleventh minute";
                    }
                  }
                  else {
                    echo "u got destroyed in the tenth minute";
                  }
                }
                else {
                  echo "u got destroyed in the ninth minute";
                }
              }
              else {
                echo "u got destroyed in the eight minute";
              }
            }
            else {
              echo "u got destroyed in the seventh minute";
            }
          }
          else {
            echo "u got destroyed in the sixt minute";
          }
        }
        else {
          echo "u got destroyed in the fifth minute";
        }
      }
      else {
        echo "u got destroyed in the fourth minute";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "u got destroyed in the third minute";
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "u got destroyed in the second minute";
  }
}
else {
  echo "u got destroyed in the first minute";
}
}
```

There's a syntax error that's hard to spot when the code isn't properly formatted. There's one too many `}` at the end.

Should I also add that this code is completely and utterly unacceptable? I can't even tell which problem you're trying to solve here. Your statement that there's "no other way" just isn't true, there are always many other ways to solve a problem.

I do understand that we all need to learn somehow, and in the beginning we struggle to get anything to work. Coding is not easy and correct coding has always been hard. Just make a simple rule for yourself: "I shall never again nest many if statements!", and you'll be fine.